# XGBoostError: problem with pipeline and scikit.learn

Tags: pandas, scikit-learn

I am very new to Python and ML. I have been doing few courses from Kaggle and working on pipelines.Everything seemed to work fine without the pipelines but got XGBoostError when I piped it all. I have an issue with my code but I cannot figure it out. Here below is the code and the error after:

```
X_full = pd.read_csv(train_path).copy()
X_test = pd.read_csv(test_path).copy()

def cleaning(var):    
    q1, q3 = np.percentile(var['Fare'], [25, 75])
    iqr = q3 - q1
    lower_bound_val = q1 - (1.5 * iqr)
    upper_bound_val = q3 + (1.5 * iqr)
    var = var[(var['Fare'] >= lower_bound_val) & (var['Fare'] < upper_bound_val)].copy()
    var['family_size'] = var.SibSp + var.Parch
    drop_cols = ['PassengerId', 'Name', 'Parch', 'SibSp', 'Ticket', 'Cabin', 'Embarked']
    var = var.drop(drop_cols, axis=1)
    return var

get_cleaning = FunctionTransformer(cleaning, validate=False)

age_transformer = SimpleImputer(missing_values=np.nan, strategy='median')
age_col = ['Age']
sex_transformer = OneHotEncoder(handle_unknown='ignore', sparse=False)
sex_col = ['Sex']

# Define the model
xgboost_m = XGBRegressor(random_state=0)

prepro_col = ColumnTransformer(
    transformers=[
        ('age', age_transformer, age_col),
        ('sex', sex_transformer, sex_col)
])

pl = Pipeline(steps=[('get_cleaning', get_cleaning),
                     ('prepro_col', prepro_col),
                     ('XGBoost', xgboost_m)
                    ])

# Drop assign target to y and drop from X_full
y = X_full.Survived
X_full.drop(['Survived'], axis=1, inplace=True)

# Split data
X_train, X_valid, y_train, y_valid = train_test_split(X_full, y, train_size=0.8, test_size=0.2, random_state=0)

pl.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

And here the error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
XGBoostError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-887-676d922c8ba5> in <module>
----> 1 pl.fit(X_train, y_train)

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sklearn/pipeline.py in fit(self, X, y, **fit_params)
    333             if self._final_estimator != 'passthrough':
    334                 fit_params_last_step = fit_params_steps[self.steps[-1][0]]
--> 335                 self._final_estimator.fit(Xt, y, **fit_params_last_step)
    336 
    337         return self

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/xgboost/sklearn.py in fit(self, X, y, sample_weight, base_margin, eval_set, eval_metric, early_stopping_rounds, verbose, xgb_model, sample_weight_eval_set, callbacks)
    546                               obj=obj, feval=feval,
    547                               verbose_eval=verbose, xgb_model=xgb_model,
--> 548                               callbacks=callbacks)
    549 
    550         if evals_result:

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/xgboost/training.py in train(params, dtrain, num_boost_round, evals, obj, feval, maximize, early_stopping_rounds, evals_result, verbose_eval, xgb_model, callbacks)
    210                            evals=evals,
    211                            obj=obj, feval=feval,
--> 212                            xgb_model=xgb_model, callbacks=callbacks)
    213 
    214 

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/xgboost/training.py in _train_internal(params, dtrain, num_boost_round, evals, obj, feval, xgb_model, callbacks)
     73         # Skip the first update if it is a recovery step.
     74         if version % 2 == 0:
---> 75             bst.update(dtrain, i, obj)
     76             bst.save_rabit_checkpoint()
     77             version += 1

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/xgboost/core.py in update(self, dtrain, iteration, fobj)
   1159             _check_call(_LIB.XGBoosterUpdateOneIter(self.handle,
   1160                                                     ctypes.c_int(iteration),
-> 1161                                                     dtrain.handle))
   1162         else:
   1163             pred = self.predict(dtrain, output_margin=True, training=True)

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/xgboost/core.py in _check_call(ret)
    186     """
    187     if ret != 0:
--> 188         raise XGBoostError(py_str(_LIB.XGBGetLastError()))
    189 
    190 

XGBoostError: [22:28:42] ../src/data/data.cc:530: Check failed: labels_.Size() == num_row_ (712 vs. 622) : Size of labels must equal to number of rows.
Stack trace:
  [bt] (0) /opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/xgboost/lib/libxgboost.so(+0xa5dc4) [0x7f27232f2dc4]
  [bt] (1) /opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/xgboost/lib/libxgboost.so(+0x106c92) [0x7f2723353c92]
  [bt] (2) /opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/xgboost/lib/libxgboost.so(+0x1a84b7) [0x7f27233f54b7]
  [bt] (3) /opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/xgboost/lib/libxgboost.so(+0x1aae4e) [0x7f27233f7e4e]
  [bt] (4) /opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/xgboost/lib/libxgboost.so(XGBoosterUpdateOneIter+0x55) [0x7f27232e4f35]
  [bt] (5) /opt/conda/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload/../../libffi.so.6(ffi_call_unix64+0x4c) [0x7f2783ff0630]
  [bt] (6) /opt/conda/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload/../../libffi.so.6(ffi_call+0x22d) [0x7f2783feffed]
  [bt] (7) /opt/conda/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload/_ctypes.cpython-37m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so(_ctypes_callproc+0x2ce) [0x7f278323c60e]
  [bt] (8) /opt/conda/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload/_ctypes.cpython-37m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so(+0x13044) [0x7f278323d044]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error indicates that, `labels_.Size() == num_row_ (712 vs. 622)` , your have 622 rows and 712 label, that isn't equal. Check your dataset and try again. In your dataset `y = X_full.Survived` is label/ Target Output.

Comment: What is exactly a label? In the pipeline, the data frame gets reduced from 712 to 622 rows.

Comment: How can I do that @ashraful? Sorry but I am very new.